# Javascript Window.open: Accessing DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, youtube

I have been experimenting with window.open popups.
I have tried the following code [with shortened URL shown here]:

```
var sub=window.open('http://youtube.com...','Subscribe to Boss Gamerz','height=170,width=390');
sub.document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
sub.focus();
```

Which opens a new popup but does not remove scrollbars as I intended it to.
Instead, chromium gives me an error message in the console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com"
from accessing a frame with origin "swappedout://".  The frame requesting
access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol
of "swappedout". Protocols must match.
```

How can I make this function properly?

Comment: You can't, due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). Youtube provides an [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), I'm not familiar with it, but maybe you can find something ...

Comment: Currently you can do some things passed as `window.open()` parameters, described at **[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)**